# implicit class functions in object scala generic

Tags: scala, dictionary

I wrote this

```
def computeMap(map:Map[String, DataFrame], f: (String) => String, g: (DataFrame) => DataFrame ) : Map[String, DataFrame] = {
  map.map{ case (key, value) => (f(key), g(value) }
}
```

My problem here is that f and g function are provided by 2 implicit classes wrapped in objects ( one implicit class for string transform and the second one is for dataframe transorm)

I rather want to write:

```
def computeMap(map:Map[String, DataFrame], f: tobecompleted, g: tobecompleted ) : Map[String, DataFrame] = {
  map.map{ case (key, value) => (key.f, value.g) }
}
```

f for example can be defined

```
object Test {
 implicit class Transform(s:String) {

   def colm():String = {
     s + "ded"
  }
}
```

Is there any solution for this please ?

Comment: Can you share how would you like to call the function.

Comment: I added further details

Comment: Still, How would you want to call `computeMap` given `Transform` is in scope?

Comment: computeMap(Map, colm, seconfunction)

Comment: Then no, there is no way of doing that. `colm` is not even in the scope. I would just leave the first definition of `computeMap` and the call it like this `computeMap(Map, _.colm, _.seconfunction)` or being more verbose `computeMap(Map, key => key.colm, df => df.seconfunction)`.